# about erasing an interator of a boost multiindex

Tags: c++, iterator, boost-multi-index

I'd like to delete some element out of a `boost multi-index` container by erasing iterators while visiting the collection.

What I am not sure about is if any iterator invalidation is involved and  whether my code below would invalidate `first`and `last` iterators.

If the code below is incorrect, which is the best way considering the specific index (`ordered_unique`) below?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdint.h>
 #include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
 #include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
 #include <boost/multi_index/key_extractors.hpp>
 #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

  using namespace std;

  class MyClass{
  public:  
    MyClass(int32_t id) : id_(id) {}
    int32_t id() const
    { return id_; }
  private:  
    int32_t id_;
  };

  typedef boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> MyClass_ptr;

  typedef boost::multi_index_container<
      MyClass_ptr,
      boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::ordered_unique<
          boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<MyClass,int32_t,&MyClass::id>
        >
      >
    > Coll;

  int main() {

    Coll coll;
    // ..insert some entries 'coll.insert(MyClass_ptr(new MyClass(12)));'

    Coll::iterator first = coll.begin();
    Coll::iterator last  = coll.end();

    while(first != last) {
      if((*first)->id() == 3)
        coll.erase(first++);
      else 
        ++first;    
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `erase` for containers returns an iterator is to use that result:

```
first = coll.erase(first);
```

Then you don't have to worry about how the underlying implementation handles `erase` or whether it shifts elements around. (In a `vector`, for instance, your code would've skipped an element in your iteration) However, the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/indices.html#rnd_vs_vector) does state that:

> It is tempting to see random access indices as an analogue of std::vector for use in Boost.MultiIndex, but this metaphor can be misleading, as both constructs, though similar in many respects, show important semantic differences. An advantage of random access indices is that their iterators, as well as references to their elements, are stable, that is, they remain valid after any insertions or deletions.

Still, just seeing `coll.erase(first++)` is a flag for me, so prefer to do it the other way.

Comment: Thanks Barry. Is 'last' iterator going to remain the same until the while loop ends? I stored coll.end() before the loop begins so I am wondering whether is it going to keep the same value after an 'erase'

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile answer is yes, `end()` is a valid iterator (just like an iterator pointing to an actual element) and always remains valid after erasure.

Comment: @Joaquin. Hi, I need a bit of clarity (sorry to be a bit pedantic here); in my post I meant if the value stored in 'last' remains valid after 'erase'. I am sure that  a call t o 'end()' will always be valid.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile the value stored in `last` remains valid.